# (PyQt5) How can i show a new window in my main window?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, event-loop

I'm trying to show a new dialog window in my main window when i click on a pushbutton. I'm facing some issues here:

1: when i create a new dialog object inside my mainWindow class, i'll have to use lambda as a slot or else it wont work. the code below works as expected:

```
class main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        new = QDialog()
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: new.show())

        self.show()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = main()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

while going like `self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(new.show)` does not work.

But if the object is created outside the main class it will run without Lambda:

```
class main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)


        self.show()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = main()

new = QDialog()
ex.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(new.show)

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I really don't understand what is happening here. AFAIK using a slot without Lambda should work as long as no arguments are passed to it.

2:

If i wanted to connect the pushbutton to a slot (in which i create a dialog object and run the show() method on it), the dialog window would appear and then immediately disappear, in this case i'll need to do `dialoginstance.exec_()` instead of `dialoginstance.show()`

```
class main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.showdiag())

        self.show()
    def showdiag(self):
        new = QDialog()
        new.exec_()    # new.show() wont work!


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = main()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: self.new =QDialog() ?

Comment: yes, using `self` makes it work with show() but why? how is `exec_()` different from `show()` that `exec_()` does not need self but `show()` does?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61123846/pyqt5-opening-second-window-from-main I was asking a similar question a while ago. It’s like exec keeps QDialog alive while without self the variable gets erased (garbage collected). Not really sure about all of this. Try with @musicamante or ellyansec they know more and how to explain better too

Comment: Correct, but this does not apply to `Qwidgets` they don't have `exec_()` and `show()` works for them.